# Как сделать иконку Options Menu белым цветом?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-menu, android-themes

Как сделать `Options Menu` белым цветом? Сейчас цвет как у `colorAccent`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тема:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в разметку меню:

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
```

Comment: О, получилось, идеально! Спасибо огромное! :)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте тему `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar` вместо `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar`.

Comment: Не могу, я использую кастомный tool bar, по этому вынужден использовать Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar